# How to convert original MySQL Datatypes in R

Tags: mysql, r, database, types, sqldatatypes

I have a MySQL database with a lot of data in it. Now I want to manipulate it with R. After I run the MySQL Query, R imports the data but converts the datatypes of the tables. e.g. `datetime` is converted to character and so on. And this is not the problem when just using the data in R. But after analyzing it I want to write it back to the MySQL database with a few changes. But the datatypes are still the converted ones from R. So the database struggles to show the newly created tables in another software. After I converted the datatypes manually in MySQL workbench they showed up. This takes ages for the big data. Now my question:

is there any way to convert the datatypes in R to the original types from MySQL before writing it back to the database?

R produces this warning:

```
10: In .local(conn, statement, ...) : Unsigned INTEGER in col 3 imported as numeric 11: In .local(conn, statement, ...) : unrecognized MySQL field type 7 in column 20 imported as character
```

The R code I run

```
dat = lapply(tables, function(table){fn$dbGetQuery(con, sprintf({"SELECT * FROM %s WHERE TIME>=(SELECT MIN(TIME) FROM %s) AND TIME <'$z'"}, table,table))}) ;
dat %<>% bind_rows()
```

with `tables` being a list of tables i want to fetch and `z` a year.

Comment: How could this be done? R doesn't know anything about MySQL types. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: R produces this warnig: 10: In .local(conn, statement, ...) :
  Unsigned INTEGER in col 3 imported as numeric
11: In .local(conn, statement, ...) :
  unrecognized MySQL field type 7 in column 20 imported as character

Comment: Please just update your question with this new informations. Don't post them as comment. The warning is useless when you don't offer the code that caused it! You have not read the link I gave you.